# Assess the quality of restoration by PSNR

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to measure the quality of an image restoration algorithm, I'm measuring [peak signal to noise ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)

```
function Q=psnr(ImRef,ImDis)
    ImRef=double(ImRef);
    ImDis=double(ImDis);
if (mean2((ImRef-ImDis).^2)~=0)
   x=max(max(ImRef))^2;
   Q=10*log10(x/mean2((ImRef-ImDis).^2));
else 
   Q=0;
end;
return
```

where `ImRef` and `ImDis` are the reference image and the restored image, the measured psnr for the entire image is different when i take part from the image. Does it make sense to measure the psnr for a part of the image?

Answer (score 1):

The PSNR as a transformation of SNR is indeed function of the number of pixels.
Hence it is expected to have it changed for different size of patches.

Regarding the other part, Well, if you are trying to restore Miss Focus blur and you restore certain "Depth" it make sense to measure the SNR at this area.
I see no problem with that.

But the main thing is that PSNR isn't really good measure of the quality of the restoration.
SSIM would be a better starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You may compute PSNR as easy as this:

```
PSNR = 10*log10(max(ImRef(:))^2/mse(ImRef(:)-ImDis(:))) ;
```